# Remove Icon but have HomeAsUp in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I what my actionbar to have a **title** and **homeAsUp** but not the logo or icon.

like this:

[image]

I tried this:

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
actionBar.setTitle("My Profile");
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
```

But it gives the application icon between the title and back arrow

Thank You

Comment: Why do you not want the icon to be present? Would it notbe easier for your users to see which app they are using after they receive a call etc?

Comment: **I don't believe that inter-platform consistency between an app's different versions is as important than consistency between apps on a single platform**  by Juhani

Comment: Some time we need this feature when your non geeky boss ask you to do the iOS UI pattern in Android! it's definitely one of the bad practices in Android! but we have to do it! if we comment on that then we are noted! :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();    
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
actionBar.setTitle("My Profile");
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
```

Comment: From documentation: **Home is presented as either an activity icon or logo**
The method: `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled (boolean showHome)`


http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean)

Comment: i find with ASB, if you setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); setHomeButtonEnabled(true); will do the same: title with up indicator, and without icon.

Answer (score 10):

Open your styles.xml file and add below codes in your Actionbar style

```
<item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
<item name="displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
<item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item> <--this do the magic!
```

p/s: I'm using Actionbar Sherlock and this works just fine

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want the icon in particular activity.

```
getActionBar().setIcon(
   new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

Comment: after this your earlier back behavior on click of (arrow+icon) this will stop working.

Answer (score 4):

To hide action bar icon following methods works for me

```
method-1:getActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
method-2:getActionBar().setIcon(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set this thing

```
actionBar.setLogo(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
getActionBar().setIcon(
new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the icon as well try using `setIcon(null)`

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle("My Profile");
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
actionBar.setIcon(null);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);//used to navigate to home
 getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);//used to hide the left caret symbol
```