# use android backAsUp with custom title bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, statusbar

I have a custom title bar, a simple relative layout, that I set as the custom title bar of my activity. But at want the android `BackAsUp` icon `<` to show up as usual (i.e. to the left of my custom layout). How do I do that? here is my code so far.

```
    this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.my_title_bar, null);
    this.getActionBar().setCustomView(v);
```

**Update:**

I have tried the answer at [Remove Icon but have HomeAsUp in ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704953/remove-icon-but-have-homeasup-in-actionbar?rq=1) they don't work. So one question, is order of setting those flags matter?

Comment: I'm not sure but did you try just including `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` and `getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);` ?

Comment: Yes. But then it shows the logo as well. Then I set `this.getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);` but it still shows the logo. I am trying to figure out how to set the logo to null.

Comment: `this.getActionBar().setLogo(null);` does not help either.

Comment: Did you try to set the icon as transparent? You can also do it in `styles.xml` and set the style for Action bar likw `<item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item> ` . See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14998204/1306419

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following combo solved the problem.

```
getActionBar().setIcon(
               new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
        this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```