# Robolectric - screen_action_bar.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm using Robolectric, and I'm getting the following error when creating an Activity. I'm using the 2.3-Snapshot - `androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3-SNAPSHOT')`

```
android.view.InflateException: XML file jar:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar!/res/layout/screen_action_bar.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2823)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2886)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:263)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
    at com.company.app.activities.loginjoin.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:49)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    at org.fest.reflect.method.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:112)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:147)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:265)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:144)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:154)
    at com.company.app.activities.loginjoin.LoginActivityTest.setup(LoginActivityTest.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:250)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.$$robo$$PhoneWindow_1a87_generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2823)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.$$robo$$PhoneWindow_1a87_installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2886)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.$$robo$$PhoneWindow_1a87_setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:263)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java)
    at android.app.Activity.$$robo$$Activity_c57b_setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
    at com.company.app.activities.loginjoin.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:49)
    at android.app.Activity.$$robo$$Activity_c57b_performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.fest.reflect.method.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:112)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:147)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:265)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:144)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:154)
    at com.company.app.activities.loginjoin.LoginActivityTest.setup(LoginActivityTest.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:250)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x0 a=765015 r=0x106000d}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2063)
    at org.fest.reflect.method.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:112)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.loadDrawable(ShadowResources.java:504)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.__constructor__(ActionBarView.java:206)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:177)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2823)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2886)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:263)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
    at com.company.app.activities.loginjoin.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:49)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    at org.fest.reflect.method.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:112)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:147)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:265)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:144)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:154)
    at com.company.app.activities.loginjoin.LoginActivityTest.setup(LoginActivityTest.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:250)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
```

I see this [github issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1049) is open, but it's supposedly a Windows issue. I'm running on a Mac. I opened a [separate issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1053).

My test is as follows. It happens anytime I use the activity generation `create()` method:

```
@Config(emulateSdk = 18)
public class LoginActivityTest extends BaseRobolectricTest {

    private LoginActivity activity;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        super.setup();
        activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(LoginActivity.class).create().get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT (New Response)**:

The issue was traced to an issue when setting a color as the `android:icon` in the ActionBar. I ended up using https://stackoverflow.com/a/13705280/413254.

See the thread over on github - https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1053 for more context.

---

**Old Response**:

I was able to fix the issue by adding

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

to my theme file. However this removes the ActionBar title... which is not what I want. I suspect it's an issue with styling the ActionBar. I'll report back with my findings.

Comment: report back please :)